# DateTime.TryParse or Datetime.TryParseExact?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am converting date and time from a string. I append the date parts from my input like below

```
string joinedString = txtMonth.Text.Trim() + "/" + txtDate.Text.Trim() + "/" + txtYear.Text.Trim();
```

Generally i convert the string like below

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(joinedString, out dt))
{
    lblOutputCulture.Text = dt.ToString();
}
else
{
    lblOutputCulture.Text = "Invalid Date Time!!!";
}
```

Here i can get the datetime if the culture and datetime format of the culture is same as my string pattern. But if it is chnaged like 'dd-MM-yy' the conversion shoul failed.

To overcome this, we need to parse using InvariantCulture. For this i found 2 methods

Method 1 : Using DateTime.TryParse

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(joinedString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    lblOutput.Text = dt.ToString();
}
else
{
    lblOutput.Text = "Invalid Date Time!!!";
}
```

Here the date time is successfully converted even if the datetime format of the system is changed. Also the following advatages
 i) The date and month input is 1 digit or 2 digit
 ii) The year input is 2 digit or 4 digit

Method 2: Using DateTime.TryParseExact

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(joinedString, "M/d/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    lblOutput.Text = dt.ToString();
}
else
{
    lblOutput.Text = "Invalid Date Time!!!";
}
```

Here also datetime is converted with out culture specific but strict to the format i gave in the tryparseexact statement.

But the following are the issues for this
 i) If i gave 4 digit year input it shows invalid date and time. If i change the format to 'M/d/yyyy' i can't able to give 2 digit year number. Like if i add time part, i need to give time part mandatory.

So which one is better? Please give a suggestion. But mostly i found the second method in all blogs and forums..

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would use neither:

```
try {
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(txtYear.Text),
                             int.Parse(txtMonth.Text),
                             int.Parse(txtDate.Text));
   lblOutput.Text = dt.ToString(); //Not sure why we'd do this, but whatever
} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
   lblOutput.Text = "Invalid Date Time!!!";
}
```

This easily extends to including other parts, e.g. time, by selecting a different overload of the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a terrible solution. First, this doesn't even answer the question, like at all.  Second, this solution is terribly inefficient.  Using try catch for input validation is extremely bad programming practice and can cause serious lags in your program.

Comment: @JSON - Read the question again. Why would someone go the the effort of *building* a single string so that they can use `TryParse` when, apparently, each element is being input in a separate text field. Also, in general, I don't optimize failure paths.

Comment: OK, so you answered 1/3 of a question.  He was asking which one is better between TryParse() and TryParseExact() and asked for a suggestion.  You gave a suggestion hence 1/3.  It is a terrible because you don't know if it is a failure path.  It appears to be this time.  However, some other poor guy is going to come in here, see this, and think try catches are ok for data validation, pump it through a algorithm a couple of million times, and can't figure out why it takes 2 1/2 hours to complete. In general, I try to preach good programming practices regardless of the expected path.

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't help in adding a 2 digit year, which is part of the problem he is having.  Adding year of "16" would cause dt.Year == 0016.  You are better off using a series of if statements and some Regex to get the desired effect.